# Does Spark saveAsTable roll back when the session is killed during a write?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

When appending to a hive managed table using saveAsTable, does the work done by an incomplete saveAsTable get rolled back, or will partial information persist?

Comment: I think it will rollback because writes are first done into a `_temporary` folder which only gets committed once the operation is successful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "Roll back" while writing the table using spark. It doesn't create a transactional table when you saveAsTable. If the spark session dies while you are saving the table, the table remains at unusable state. Even if partial data is written, you probably won't be able to read the partially written data.

However the rest of the data can be read when you are using the append only hive.

Comment: Thanks, how do you consolidate this with what @philantrovert said?